# How to list signatures of public key file without importing it to keyring?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

How can I list all signatures made to a public OpenPGP key without importing it? A file with the public key is available.

I would like a similar output to `gpg --list-signatures <key-id>`, but instead of using the keyring, giving a file.

I have tried `gpg --list-packets <file>` and `pgpdump <file`, but both outputs are not very legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--show-keys --with-sig-list`:

```
curl -s 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search={fingerprint}' \
    | gpg --show-keys --with-sig-list
```

Tested in GnuPG 2.2.40. As per the release notes [the `--with-sig-list` option was added in 2.0.10](https://www.gnupg.org/download/release_notes.html) (released on 2009-01-12).